# Array forEach is only returning the first item back

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to use forEach on an Array but it is only working on the first item in Array.

I want to return a list of objects, but not in an Array

This is my Array

```
const latLngCoords = [   
  [-1.56789, 63.45547],
  [-1.44523, 63.48642],
  [-1.54635, 63.46643]

];
```

Then the way I am currently using forEach is

```
let x;

latLngCoords.forEach(e => {
  x = { lat: e[0], lng: e[1] };
});

return x;
```

The result is

```
{ lat: -1.56789, lng: 63.45547 }
```

Was expecting

```
{ lat: -1.56789, lng: 63.45547 }
{ lat: -1.44523, lng: 63.48642 }
{ lat: -1.54635, lng: 63.46643 }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to return the new array.

`forEach` just iterates over the array but doesn't return a new one.

```js
const latLngCoords = [   
  [-1.56789, 63.45547],
  [-1.44523, 63.48642],
  [-1.54635, 63.46643],
];

const result = latLngCoords.map(e => {
  return { lat: e[0], lng: e[1] };
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tigran, but I don't want to return a new a array, just a list of objects as in the expected results I put up

Comment: @Wisdom1 You want to return the list of objects and save it in the one variable(x)? if you do not want to return a new array then you need to return an object that contains these nested objects

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to return array of data.

```
const x = latLngCoords.map(cord=>({lat:cord[0],lng:cord[1]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let x=[];
const latLngCoords = [   
  [-1.56789, 63.45547],
  [-1.44523, 63.48642],
  [-1.54635, 63.46643]

];

latLngCoords.forEach((c) => {
      x.push({ lat: c[0], lng: c[1] })
})

console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach just simply iterates through an array, not giving you back results. You redeclare your x variable every time inside the forEach.

simply you use console log inside the forEach:

```
latLngCoords.forEach(e => {
console.log({ lat: e[0], lng: e[1] });
});
```

or use map to make a new array of objects:

```
let newArr = latLngCoords.map(e => ({ lat: e[0], lng: e[1] }));
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` instead of `forEach`.

`const result = latLngCoords.map(([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng}));`

```js
const latLngCoords = [   
  [-1.56789, 63.45547],
  [-1.44523, 63.48642],
  [-1.54635, 63.46643]

];

const result = latLngCoords.map(([lat, lng]) => ({ lat, lng}));
console.log(result);
```